# c# white framework -code project

Tags: c#, automation

I am new to the [White](http://white.codeplex.com/project). Can someone tell me how to run an exe file (with a log password) and print all the elements from that exe file?

I did use

```
Application application = Application.Launch("exe /password)"
```

but it is not working.

Comment: White projects are the project in which source code is not stolen or copied from another codes :-) i guess

Comment: White is a framework for automating rich client applications based on Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and SWT (Java) platforms. It is .NET based and does not require the use of any proprietary scripting languages

Comment: what does " print all the elements from that exe file" mean? Are you trying to get the control names?

Comment: so..the exe files contain a list with phone number. i want to print all the phone numbers

Comment: Can you show what you were using to do this? And how is it "not working" now? Is it giving you an error?

Answer (score 1):

Elisa
I am assuming you want to get the phone numbers from a form which contains a listview or gridview and write them to a file or some other control. So of the top of my head:) here it goes

//Launch the app

Application app = Application.Launch("full path of .exe");

//Get the main window after launching the app

Window win = app.GetWindow(Core.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("Form1"), Core.Factory.InitializeOption.NoCache);

//get the list/gridview its of type table in white

var listOfPhonesNumbers= win.Get<`Table`>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("grdPhoneNumber"));

for(int i =0; i "<" listOfPhoneNumbers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
 ///print phone number to whatever file
}

Answer (score 0):

```
#region lanch App 
// source exe file path. here it is calculator exe path
const string ExeSourceFile = @"C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe";
//Global Variable to for Application launch
White.Core.Application _application;
//Global variable to get the Main window of calculator from application.
White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.Window _mainWindow;
//start process for the above exe file location
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ExeSourceFile);
// launch the process through white application
_application = White.Core.Application.AttachOrLaunch(psi);
//Get the window of calculator from white application 
_mainWindow = _application.GetWindow
(SearchCriteria.ByText("Calculator"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
#endregion
```